# After updating gradle 2.1.2 Not at all working

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

After updating gradle 2.1.2 and studio 2.1, project not running. getting errors in mergingResources and saying unable to delete path from intermediates and etrc. If i change gradle version to 1.5.0, its working again. But gradle 2.1.2 not at all working.

Comment: Have you try to restart Android Studio ?

Comment: Yes i tried by restarting. And i tried by deleting build folder manually. But no use. Even if i create a new project, that also not running. My java version "1.8.0_60" My log is Information:Gradle tasks [:app:clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:assembleDebug]
:app:clean FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:clean'.
> Unable to delete directory: /MyApplication/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/animated-vector-drawable/23.4.0/jars
Information:BUILD FAILED

Comment: Add just went through a similar problem with gradle 2.1.2. I kept getting the message there was nothing to update, even when using the 'clean and rebuild" option.  I didn't even have the APK installed on the device, but there was nothing I could do to force it to install.  I finally just reverted back.

Comment: Yes tried by restaring, deleting build folder, clean.. everything.. But same result.. Not at all running.